# How to force a line break right after the name of the proof environment?

Tags: line-breaking, amsthm, german

I'm not experienced with LaTeX and so I couldn't really judge if this is a trivial fix.

I want to have a proof-statement on it's own line.
Currently, things get displayed like this:

```
Beweis. G1 (a ∗ b) ∗ c = a ∗ (b ∗ c) ∀a, b, c ∈ G
```

where "Beweis" is the german equivalent of "proof".
So what I am aiming for is a display that looks like this:

```
Beweis. 
G1 (a ∗ b) ∗ c = a ∗ (b ∗ c) ∀a, b, c ∈ G
```

I came up with this command-definition:

```
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}\normalfont\bfseries Beweis\newline}
```

... but it didn't work as I expected it to. Note: I really don't want to alter the way "Beweis" looks (font-size, indentation, etc.), I just want it to be displayed on its own line.

Comment: Please, don't try to emulate output, but show the code you're using.

Comment: Ok next time I'll add my code, thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof} \hfill 

\noindent
$G1 (a * b) * c = a * (b * c) \forall a, b, c \in G$.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: @Mico This might cause a page break just after "Beweis", which would look weird, isn't it?

Comment: @MichelFioc - That could be handled nicely by loading the [needspace](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/needspace/needspace.pdf) package and issuing an instruction such as `\Needspace{3\baselineskip}` before `begin{proof}`.

Comment: @Mico Another solution is to insert `\makeatletter\@afterheading\makeatother` before the `\par`.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you use amsthm package,

In this package proof is defined as :

```
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \normalfont
  \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@ \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \qed\endtrivlist
}
```

You can change it in the preambule of your document adding this code :

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par  %renew to change
  \normalfont
  \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@ \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
        \hfill \break                         %change
}{%
  \qed\endtrivlist
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}\ \\ 
$G1 \quad (a * b) * c = a * (b * c), \quad  \forall a, b, c \in G$
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't specify it correctly. I mean it exactly as I wrote it. After "Beweis", I want G1 (a * b) * c... get displayed on a new line. "Beweis (newline) G1"

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri You can see the modifications.

Comment: +1. Loading `babel` with language option `ngerman` (don't use `german` unless you're dealing with historical texts...) should make `\renewcommand*{\proofname}{Beweis}` unnecessary.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much. I have taken your suggestion.